# Is there any such thing such as a javascript window onidle event

Tags: javascript, events

```
function init() {
    //$.ajax({url: blah-blah-blah...});
    window.myTimer = setTimeout(init, 1000);
    return;
}
```

I have my `init();` loop running, and I would like to clear it when my window object is being changed (resized, moved, etc...).

When I am done doing this, I was hoping to be able to call something similar to: `window.addEventListener('idle', function() { if (!window.myTimer) { init(); } });`

I thought it would it be safe enough to just resume via:

`window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() { if (!window.myTimer) { init(); });`

however this one is not even working as I had expected for this purpose, and it ignores the scroll aspect. I've also tried the `onchange` event and that one fires as things are changing.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback

Comment: @ChristopherHarris Thanks for the link, I didn't see that on MDN when I was looking at the window events, I will take a deeper look as it sounds like it is exactly what I need.

Comment: Unfortunately not available in IE/edge, but you may find a polyfill somewhere.

Comment: And unavailable in Safari

Comment: @ChristopherHarris could you formalize this into an answer, so I can give you credit for getting me to my answer? Anyway, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing the quick read, and getting a moment to test it all out; here is the basics of my interpretation of the `requestIdleCallback` function ([MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback)).

```js
/* Global Variable Declarations */
window.myTimer = null;
window.counter = 0;
/* END Global Variable Declarations */

function init() {
 /* My Custom checking code here */
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = window.counter+"";
 console.log(window.counter);
 window.counter += 1;
 /* End My Custom checking code */
 
 /* Non-Blocking Loop */
 window.myTimer = setTimeout(init, 50);
 /* End Non-Blocking Loop */
}

/* Event Listener Declarations */
window.addEventListener("change", function() { clearInterval(window.myTimer); window.myTimer = null; });
window.requestIdleCallback(function() { if (!window.myTimer) { init(); } });
/* END Event Listener Declarations */
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

I tested the posted code along with my jQuery ajax code in Chrome, and it all seems to be working well.

This was very strait forward in comparison to trying to trap all of the other possible event states!

---

I tested the following interpretation in Edge, and it seemed to work pretty well:

```js
function msDiff(timeStamp) {
 var a = timeStamp;
 var oMS = (a.getHours()*60*60*1000) + (a.getMinutes()*60*1000) + (a.getSeconds()*1000) + a.getMilliseconds();
 var b = new Date();
 var nMS = (b.getHours()*60*60*1000) + (b.getMinutes()*60*1000) + (b.getSeconds()*1000) + b.getMilliseconds();
 return nMS - oMS;
}

/* Global Variable Declarations */
window.myTimer = null;
window.myPause = new Date();
window.counter = 0;
/* END Global Variable Declarations */

function init() {
 /* My Custom checking code here */
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = window.counter+"";
 console.log(window.counter);
 window.counter += 1;
 /* End My Custom checking code */
 
 /* Non-Blocking Loop */
 window.myTimer = setTimeout(init, 50);
 /* End Non-Blocking Loop */
}

function myPauseLoop() {
 if (msDiff(window.myPause) > 500) {
  init();
  return;
 } else {
  setTimeout(myPauseLoop, 500);
 }
}

/* Event Listener Declarations */
window.addEventListener("change", function() { 
 clearInterval(window.myTimer); 
 window.myTimer = null; 
 window.myPause = new Date();
});
/* End Event Listener Declarations */

init();
```

```html
<div id='counter'></div>
```

Comment: @ChristopherHarris OK, I just wanted to show my appreciation for pointing me to exactly where I needed to go, and give you the reputation credit for it.